Is the source code of Alan Dain Sample's m5 macro processor lost?
I've recently come across the User's Guide to the M5 Macro Language by Alan Dain Samples. The guide says that the source code is available at thor.ece.uc.edu:pub/dain/m5. However, this seems not be the case anymore (the paper is also already more than 30 years old).
Since I'd like to take a look into M5, I am wondering if the source code is lost for good.

There''s an m5 in github, but I don't know if it's the same m5 (it would seem like a pretty obvious name for a follow-on to m4). https://github.com/eyeinsky/m5  OH there's another one: https://github.com/rweda/M5

Don't think that is the same M5, dave. René, I think on this site the question is a bit redundant, as an answer of "I know it existed, hence I take interest in it" is very valid here, but: I don't know anything ever implemented in M5, outside of what is in the manual. Especially, I don't think there was any code flow from M5 back into any M4 interpreters.

eyeinsky/m5 does not resemble of any comcenpt I've read in the paper. rweda/M5 is a library of macros implemented in m4 while Alan D. Samples explicitely states that his implementation of M5 is more powerful than m4 (so I believe it's unrelated, too)

@Marcus I don’t think “I know it existed, hence I take interest in it” would be a valid answer; it doesn’t address the question… Why is the question redundant? Asking if someone has the source code for something mentioned in a 30-year-old paper seems on topic to me.

@StephenKitt ah sorry, misunderstanding: If I asked René *why do you want to know about M5?", then the answer "It existed, hence I care" would be perfectly valid, in a human sense. I don't think "why do you care?" is relevant to on- or off-topicness anywhere here, anyways :) I was just honestly curious!

@Marcus ah, right, that makes more sense. Your comment didn’t include the question you were answering, so the theoretical answer looked like an answer to the main question ;-).

Yeah, I could have phrased that waaaaaay better. My apologies - especially to @RenéNyffenegger.

Have you tried contacting the late author's (still living) doctoral advisor, Paul N. Hilfinger? If he doesn't himself have a copy, he might know where one is archived, or who else might have a copy.

Prof. Hilfinger has informed me that M5 was an unofficial personal side project and he had no copy, and that it is unlikly that it's possible to retrieve the 33 year old source code at this point. He also gave me another hint where for futher inquiries, so I am not yet entirely done with my search.

That is anonymous ftp to a very specific server. That server is most likely long gone
